# Emberjs - Event when new element is insert in template

Tags: ember.js

I have a function in my controller that refresh my model asynchronously to download images for a gallery.

I need to trigger a function that put my images in columns (3 images per column), but this function is triggered only once when I load the page and of course there is only one image loaded at this time because the event is too fast for the download.

Is there is any event that I could use to call this function every time I have a new images in my loaded ?
Is it possible to detect if the DOM has been updated ?

I am using a `{{#each img in gallery}}` to display my images.

[edit] My object is like this :

```
{
    images: [
        0: "url1",
        1: "url2",
        3: "url3"
    ]
}
```

But when it come to download images, it replace every element of the images array with an object like this :

```
{
    images: [
        0: {
            key: "key1",
            base64: "base64_1"
        },
        1: {
            key: "key2",
            base64: "base64_2"
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up an observer that detects changes in your `gallery`. In your controller:

```
galleryChanged: function() {
    // Perform logic here
}.observes('gallery.@each')
```

That should work for most situations. If you need something a bit more efficient, you can try using the [arrayComputed](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_arrayComputed) function. It is a bit more complicated though.

Comment: It's kinda working, but only when its begin to load the first image. When the others images are added to the model and displayed on the template, it's not working.. its that observes is observing every time the @each is called ?

Comment: You might want to refine the dependent key so that it updates when it gets the data you want. For example, if your images have a `src` attribute, use `gallery.@each.src` instead. That should update you any time an item is added or removed, or the `src` attribute of an item changes.

Comment: I understand, I should have said that my array of images would be slightly more complicated than that. I have updated the main post for you to see what I'm doing. In images[] there is already all of the url as a single element, but I replace each element by an object with a key and a base64 of the images. How can I trigger the modification of the images array ?

Comment: I would say that _replacing_ the objects in the array is probably a bad idea. I would suggest having objects with empty `key` and `base64` properties, then fill them in. But either way, observing `gallery.@each.key` and `gallery.@each.base64` should still alert you of changes and long as the objects are Ember objects.